# How to replace everything between {} [] () braces from a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I want to remove everything inside braces. For example, if string is:

```
[hi] helloz [hello] (hi) {jhihi}
```

then, I want the output to be only `helloz`.

I am using the following code, however it seems to me that there should be a better way of doing it, is there?

```
$name = "[hi] helloz [hello] (hi) {jhihi}";
$new  =  preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$name); 
$new = preg_replace('/\[.*\]/', '', $new);  
$new = preg_replace('/\{.*\}/', '', $new);  
echo $new;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work:

```
$name = "[hi] helloz [hello] (hi) {jhihi}";
echo preg_replace('/[\[{\(].*?[\]}\)]/' , '', $name);
```

Paste it somewhere like: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ to see it work.

Comment: you will have problem if you have another closing brace inside one of the braces something like this `$name = "[h)i] helloz [hello] (hi) {jhihi}";`

Comment: Yep, but that wasn't one of the options so I didn't take it into consideration. No need to make things harder then they need to be.

Comment: @DamienOvereem no worries (i agree), I just cautioned the OP not to get into problems later.

Answer (score 3):

[old answer]

If needed, the pattern that can deal with nested parenthesis and square or curly brackets:

```
$pattern = '~(?:(\()|(\[)|(\{))(?(1)(?>[^()]++|(?R))*\))(?(2)(?>[^][]++|(?R))*\])(?(3)(?>[^{}]++|(?R))*\})~';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```

---

[EDIT]

A pattern that only removes well balanced parts and that takes in account the three kinds of brackets:

```
$pattern = '~
    \[ [^][}{)(]*+ (?: (?R) [^][}{)(]* )*+  ]
  |
    \( [^][}{)(]*+ (?: (?R) [^][}{)(]* )*+ \)
  |
    {  [^][}{)(]*+ (?: (?R) [^][}{)(]* )*+  }
~xS';
```

This pattern works well but the additional type check is a bit overkill when the goal is only to remove bracket parts in a string. However it can be used as a subpattern to check if all kind of brackets are balanced in a string.

---

A pattern that removes only well balanced parts, but this time, only the outermost type of bracket is taken in account, other types of brackets inside are ignored *(same behavior than the old answer but more efficient and without the useless conditional tests)*:

```
$pattern = '~
    \[ ( [^][]*+ (?: \[ (?1) ] [^][]* )*+ )  ]
  |
    \( ( [^)(]*+ (?: \( (?2) ] [^)(]* )*+ ) \)
  |
     { ( [^}{]*+ (?:  { (?3) } [^}{]* )*+ )  }
~xS';
```

Comment: Compilation failed: recursive call could loop indefinitely at offset 34 on line 4

Comment: @ThiagoPires: thanks, but in fact this pattern is complicated for nothing, it's possible to do the same in a more efficient way. I will edit this answer.