# How to remove text inside brackets and parentheses at the same time with any whitespace before if present?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to clean a string in PHP using the following code, but I am not sure how to get rid of the text inside brackets and parentheses at the same time with any whitespace before if present.

The code I am using is:

```php
$string = "Deadpool 2 [Region 4](Blu-ray)";
echo preg_replace("/\[[^)]+\]/","",$string);
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Deadpool [](Blu-ray)
```

However, the desired output is:

```
Deadpool 2
```

Using the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19948660) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2359921) questions, it is not clear how to remove both one type of matches and the other one while also removing the optional whitespace before them.

Comment: @snowflakes With only one sample string we can only offer you a general solution.  If you give 10 different strings, some of which should reveal any fringe cases, we can develop our own logic for your task -- instead of blindly accepting your logic.  I see that you've received an acceptable answer, but with an improved question, we may be able to offer you a superior answer.

Comment: This question is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384914/answerer-adds-to-question-requirements-in-order-to-re-open-it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four main points here:

- String between parentheses can be matched with `\([^()]*\)`
- String between square brackets can be matched with `\[[^][]*]` (or `\[[^\]\[]*\]` if you prefer to escape literal `[` and `]`, in PCRE, it is stylistic, but in some other regex flavors, it might be a must)
- You need [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either this or that pattern and account for any whitespaces before these patterns
- Since after removing these strings you may get leading and trailing spaces, you need to `trim` the string.

You may use

```
$string = "Deadpool 2 [Region 4](Blu-ray)";
echo trim(preg_replace("/\s*(?:\[[^][]*]|\([^()]*\))/","", $string));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WNUXSS/2) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/tQQ7O).

The `\[[^][]*]` part matches strings between `[` and `]` having no other `[` and `]` inside and `\([^()]*\)` matches strings between `(` and `)` having no other parentheses inside. `trim` removes leading/trailing whitespace.

Regex [graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cs*(%3F%3A%5C%5B%5B%5E%5C%5D%5B%5D*%5D%7C%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*%5C))) and explanation:

[image]

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:` - start of a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do):

  - `\[[^][]*]` - `[`, zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (note you may keep these brackets inside a character class unescaped in a PCRE pattern if `]` is right after initial `[`, in JS, you would have to escape `]` by all means, `[^\][]*`)
  - `|` - or (an [alternation operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html))
  - `\([^()]*\)` - `(`, any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and a `)`
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

Based on just the one sample input there are some simpler approaches.

```
$string = "Deadpool 2 [Region 4](Blu-ray)";
var_export(preg_replace("~ [[(].*~", "", $string));

echo "\n";

var_export(strstr($string, ' [', true));
```

Output:

```
'Deadpool 2'
'Deadpool 2'
```

These assume that the start of the unwanted substring begins with space opening square brace.

The `strstr()` technique requires that the space-brace sequence exists in the string.

If the unwanted substring marker is not consistently included, then you can use:

```
var_export(explode(' [', $string, 2)[0]);
```

This will put the unwanted substring in explode's output array at `[1]` and the wanted substring in `[0]`.